# How to convert from cartesian to polar equation

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I am trying to convert the equation $y=4/x$ into a polar equation.

I have done this work but I am not sure if it is right.  I just subsituted $r\sin(\theta)$ for $y$ and $r\cos(\theta)$ for $x$ and solved for $r$ , which gave me $r = \sqrt{4\over (\sin(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta))}$.

Is this correct? Or am I going about this all wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Did you graph them in wolfram alpha to check?

Comment: It looks to be correct

Comment: Yes I just did and it is the same graph as y=4/x.  Thanks for the response @jgon

Comment: @user3554599 np, wolfram's usually good at sanity checks like that.

Comment: You can simplify the expression as $r = \sqrt{\frac 8{\sin(2\theta)}}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes.   You have $xy = 4$ in cartesian coordinates, so in polar coordinates that is indeed: $$r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) =4$$

You can leave it at that, or rearrange to suit.   I recommend using $ 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=\sin(2\theta)$ .

$$r^2\,\sin(2\theta) = 8$$

$$r = +2\sqrt{2\csc(2\theta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is essentially correct; as usual, one must take care when taking square roots as one does here. Substituting as in the question gives
$$r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta = 4,$$
which is equivalent to
$$r = \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{\sin \theta \cos \theta}}.$$
In our case, however, we have (in polar coordinates) that
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{\sin (\theta + \pi) \cos (\theta + \pi)}}, \theta + \pi \right)_p
&= \left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{\sin \theta \cos \theta + \pi)}}, \theta + \pi \right)_p \\
&= -\left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{\sin \theta \cos \theta + \pi)}}, \theta\right)_p .
\end{align}
Taking the positive branch (the choice $+$ of $\pm$) defines a polar function
$$r(\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{4}{\sin \theta \cos \theta}},$$ and the above computation shows that this function traces out all of the curve, i.e., that we don't miss any points by discarding the negative branch (the choice $-$ of $\pm$).

Note by the way that we can simplify our expression some using the double-angle identity $\sin 2 \theta = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$; rearranging gives
$$r(\theta) = 2 \sqrt{2 \csc 2 \theta}.$$ This makes perhaps clearer, too, that $r(\theta)$ is only defined for $\theta$ corresponding to angles in the first and third quadrants.